# Simple video editing in azure/.net

Tags: .net, azure, video-editing

I have azure-backed mobile app that allows users to upload videos and then streams them. Current task is to add some overlay to the videos. As long as videos can be downloaded by the users the only option is editing video file itself.
What is the easiest way to implement this (I do not have much azure experience)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.  Azure Media Services will support advert insertion into video content - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn387398.aspx.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for though.  It's important to remember that at present Media Services is an ingestion, storage, encoding and serving platform for video media - it's not intended as a full video production workflow platform.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Though advert insertion is not what I whant. I need to add simple animation for data representation. I have logic which is nessesary to generate frames for this animation, so I only need to add it to the video as an overlay

Comment: You could build a workflow to host the logic within a Worker Role.  If you're uploading the file from Azure Mobile Services you could place a message on a queue that the Worker subscribes to - when a new blob arrives you could process it and insert the overlay and then write back to blob storage (or to another storage account that your Media Services uses).